# Virtual and system mailboxes - how to set passdb propperly

Tags: email-server, dovecot

I've just configured email on my server.
Gentoo, Postfix, Dovecot, Amavisd, ClamAV and Spamassasin

I am using LMTP for delivering virtual mails, works great.
I am using standard postfix deliver method (mailbox_transport) for system users.

But since I'm using spamassasin I want to move all emails with Spam header to Junk/ directory. For this I use dovecot-sieve.

But now I have a problem with system accounts. Since they are not delivered with dovecot, sieve is not able to move them.

I tried to pass my local email to dovecot (also with lmtp, but setting mailbox_transport the same as virtual_transport) but next problem occured.
I set up two passdbs and two userdbs, first with pam + passwd, second using passwd-file and static.

**For local users whole username + domain is used causing PAM to fail in matching local users to itself.
If i change variable auth_username_format to %n (which is user only) %d becomes empty and virtual mailboxes stops working.**

How can I use lmtp for both system and virtual mailboxes?

This is my part of dovecot responsible for logging in:

```
passdb {
        driver = passwd-file
        args = username_format=%u /home/vmail/%d/passwd
        skip = authenticated
}
userdb {
        driver = static
        args = uid=500 gid=500 home=/home/vmail/%d mail=maildir:~/%n
}
passdb {
        args = imap
        driver = pam
}
userdb {
        driver = passwd
}
```

Comment: This should help http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Authentication/MultipleDatabases

Comment: I've seen it, but there is still no solution for passing name with and without domain